# WPF Textbox does not allows input when it is displayed in context menu on system tray

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to provide search functionality on context menu displayed in the system tray. I am using `System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon` class to display the context menu in the tray. Basically this search should allow the user to find the required menu from the context menu. For that, I added the WPF textbox like this in the below image, but it does not allow me to type the text.

Is there any way to handle the text input on this?

[image]

Here is my code,
**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SysTray_Sample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SysTray_Sample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="NotifierContextMenu"

                    Placement="MousePoint">
            <MenuItem Header="First" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
            <MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="True">
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <TextBox Text="Test" Width="120" />
                </MenuItem.Header>
            </MenuItem>
            
            <MenuItem Header="Open" Click="Menu_Open"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Close" Click="Menu_Close"/>

        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Height="22" Width="180" Content="Right click over me">
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click" Header="Minimize to system tray"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Desktop mode"/>
                    <TextBox Width="150"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon _trayIcon;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _trayIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
            _trayIcon.MouseDown += MyNotifyIcon_MouseDown;
            _trayIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"Resources\add.ico");
            _trayIcon.MouseDoubleClick += MyNotifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick;
        }

        private void MyNotifyIcon_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                ContextMenu menu = (ContextMenu)this.FindResource("NotifierContextMenu");
                menu.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }

        private void MyNotifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            _trayIcon.Visible = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        }

        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            _trayIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Minimize Sucessful";
            _trayIcon.BalloonTipText = "Minimized the app ";
            _trayIcon.ShowBalloonTip(400);
            _trayIcon.Visible = true;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void Menu_Open(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Open");
        }

        private void Menu_Close(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Close");
        }
    }
```

Comment: There seems to be focusing issue. Usually, `System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip` is used to add a context menu to `System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon` because they are both designed for WinForms.

Comment: @emoacht: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I want to achieve this with WPF context menu itself. I fixed this by using the following code,
 [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long hour of searching, I found the following solution which worked for my case.
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/184429/Text-box-is-not-working-in-WPF-Popup

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        public static void ActivateVisual(FrameworkElement contextMenu)
        {
            var fromVisual = HwndSource.FromDependencyObject(contextMenu);
            HwndSource source = (HwndSource)fromVisual;
            IntPtr handle = source.Handle;

            SetForegroundWindow(handle);
        }
```

Here is my complete **MainWindow.xaml.cs** code,

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon _trayIcon;

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        public static void ActivateVisual(FrameworkElement contextMenu)
        {
            var fromVisual = HwndSource.FromDependencyObject(contextMenu);
            HwndSource source = (HwndSource)fromVisual;
            IntPtr handle = source.Handle;

            SetForegroundWindow(handle);
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _trayIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
            _trayIcon.MouseDown += MyNotifyIcon_MouseDown;
            _trayIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"C:\Users\nambi\source\repos\SysTray_Sample\SysTray_Sample\Resources\add.ico");
            _trayIcon.MouseDoubleClick += MyNotifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick;
        }

        private void MyNotifyIcon_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                ContextMenu menu = (ContextMenu)this.FindResource("NotifierContextMenu");                
                menu.IsOpen = true;
                ActivateVisual(this.ContextMenu);
            }
        }

        private void MyNotifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            _trayIcon.Visible = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        }

        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            _trayIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Minimize Sucessful";
            _trayIcon.BalloonTipText = "Minimized the app ";
            _trayIcon.ShowBalloonTip(400);
            _trayIcon.Visible = true;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }



        private void Menu_Open(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ActivateVisual(this);
            MessageBox.Show("Open");
        }



        private void Menu_Close(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ActivateVisual(this);
            MessageBox.Show("Close");
        }
    }
```